# useEffect is not being called when dependency is changed

Tags: reactjs

**loadMoreMessages** this is being called when the **scrollTop** gets to 0. and calling **setScrollPosition** but the **useEffect** is not being called.

**setMessages** is working fine

```
const [scrollPosition, setScrollposition] = useState('')
const { messages, setMessages } = useMessages()

let getMessages = ({onSuccess, onError, finaly = f => f}) => {
        socket.emit('get:messages', (err, respo) => {
            if(err) {
                onError(err)
            }
            else {
                console.log('respo ', respo)
                else {
                    onSuccess(respo)
                }
            }
        })
    }

let loadMoreMessages = () => {
  getMessages({
    onError: err => console.log(err),
      onSuccess: data => {                  
        setMessages({
          type: 'update',
          data
        })
        console.log('messages updated') // the code dose reach here
        setScrollposition('update')
      }
   })
 }

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(scrollPosition)
}, [scrollPosition])
```

Comment: Well, that part of the code looks fine. Can you add the rest of the component?

Comment: you sure the code logic reaches `setScrollposition`? Instead of it, if you would put a `console.log` would it log something?

Comment: And that code snippet actually comes from inside a function component? Not, say, a class component's render function?

Comment: only getMessages is on its own file the rest is in the same file.

Comment: yes they are inside a function component.

Comment: Observation: if you're literally setting it to 'update' it's not going to do anything after the first time, because `scrollPosition` will not have changed.

Comment: i think that's it. but i still want to trigger that useEffect after every new messages are loaded. any suggestions?

Comment: setScrollposition('"')
setScrollposition('update')

this solved the problem. if there is a better way?

Comment: If you want to trigger it when new messages are loaded, why not have the effect depend on `messages` instead?

Comment: i was using that but every time the messages change, like when new message is sent, when loading older messages,  when changing the messages to seen and so on, the scroll keep moving around so i did this to have more control.

Answer (score 0):

might you can do this

```
useEffect(()=>{
  if(scrollPosition === 'something'){
     loadMoreMessages();
  }
},[scrollPosition])
```